# How to add flash playing capability to android app?

Tags: android, flash

My android app has a web browser component which is supposed to play flash content from the internet. I don't want to tell the users to separately download adobe flash to access flash content on my app. How can flash playing capability be added to my app? Thanks?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't heard of any third party flash interpreter that you could put in your application, like a library.

Honestly, you should rethink what you're serving up to mobile clients. All mobile platforms are no longer supported - Adobe has stopped development of Adobe Flash Android - as there are alternate ways to do what Flash used to accomplish.

Edit:
This is a great introduction to the `<audio>` tag in HTML5. You will have to double check which formats are streamable to all devices. I believe MP3 should work in iOS and Android. http://www.position-absolute.com/articles/introduction-to-the-html5-audio-tag-javascript-manipulation/

Comment: OK. I need to display a music player from a radio website. It(the player) is flash based. What other techniques could be used to display it? Thanks.

Comment: @ankitrawat, Adapt your website to work on mobile phones - or use a tool, such as `PhoneGap` to help with your port.

Comment: @ankitrawat I just updated my answer to include an example for an HTML5 audio player.

Comment: @jlindenbaum So, I would be able to play my flash based content using that html5 method..? I don't own the radio site, so cannot change the player on the website itself..

Comment: No, you would have to stream the actual MP3 (or any acceptable audio stream) to that HTML5 audio interface. You'd have to know the paths that the original Flash player was using, and see if they're compatible with HMTL5 video. You can't just take the Flash player and jam it into `<audio>`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have one more question. I don't have API access for the site. Would I be able to know the paths the original flash player was using?

Comment: Without going into too much detail: Fire up Wireshark and start inspecting traffic.